# Improve performance, reduce security calls

Tags: pine-script

I wrote a script to gather the contraction periods(using BB and KC) on different time frames and report those results to a table. Depended on the chart's time frame, different time frames are returned to the table.

Here is the function for the script that gathers the contraction:

```
resolution_squeeze(D)=>
    ma = security(syminfo.tickerid, D, sma(source,length))
    bb = security(syminfo.tickerid, D, stdev(source,length))
    kc = security(syminfo.tickerid, D, sma(tr,length))
    upBB = ma + bb * 2
    lowBB = ma - bb * 2
    upKCWide = ma + kc * 2
    lowKCWide = ma - kc * 2
    upKCNormal = ma + kc * 1.5
    lowKCNormal = ma - kc * 1.5
    upKCNarrow = ma + kc
    lowKCNarrow = ma - kc
    
    //Squeeze Type
    sqzOnWide  = (lowBB >= lowKCWide) and (upBB <= upKCWide) //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK
    sqzOnNormal  = (lowBB >= lowKCNormal) and (upBB <= upKCNormal) //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED
    sqzOnNarrow  = (lowBB >= lowKCNarrow) and (upBB <= upKCNarrow) //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE
    sqzOffWide = (lowBB < lowKCWide) and (upBB > upKCWide) //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN
    noSqz  = (sqzOnWide == false) and (sqzOffWide == false) //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE
    
    //Squeeze Color
    sq_color = noSqz ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow ? color.orange : sqzOnNormal ? color.red : sqzOnWide ? color.black : color.lime
    sq_color
```

Then I use the follow if\else to different which time frame to report back:

```
if timeframe.multiplier>= 1 and timeframe.multiplier< 60 and timeframe.isminutes==true //1-59min
    __13:= resolution_squeeze("15"),  _03:="15m"
    __14:= resolution_squeeze("30"),  _04:="30m"
    __15:= resolution_squeeze("60"),  _05:="1H"
    __16:= resolution_squeeze("120"),  _06:="2H"
    __17:= resolution_squeeze("180"),  _07:="3H"
    __18:= resolution_squeeze("240"), _08:="4H"
    __19:= resolution_squeeze("1D"),  _09:="1D"
    
else if timeframe.multiplier> 59 and timeframe.multiplier<=1440 and timeframe.isminutes==true //60min-23h59m
    __13:= resolution_squeeze("60"), _03:="1H"
    __14:= resolution_squeeze("120"), _04:="2H"
    __15:= resolution_squeeze("180"), _05:="3H"
    __16:= resolution_squeeze("240"), _06:="4H"
    __17:= resolution_squeeze("1D"),  _07:="1D"
    __18:= resolution_squeeze("2D"),  _08:="2D"
    __19:= resolution_squeeze("3D"),  _09:="3D"
    __20:= resolution_squeeze("1W"),  _10:="1W"
    
else if timeframe.multiplier>= 1 and timeframe.multiplier<= 7 and timeframe.isdaily==true //1day+
    __13:= resolution_squeeze("1D"),  _03:="1D"
    __14:= resolution_squeeze("2D"),  _04:="2D"
    __15:= resolution_squeeze("3D"),  _05:="3D"
    __16:= resolution_squeeze("1W"),  _06:="1W"
    __17:= resolution_squeeze("2W"),  _07:="2W"
    __18:= resolution_squeeze("3W"),  _08:="3W"
```

This script takes a bit to load. I am fairly new to pine script, but are there some way to improve the performance or reduce the number of security calls, without reducing the time frames? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example for point right direction:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

selectTF(i)=>
    timeframe.multiplier>= 1 and timeframe.multiplier< 60 and timeframe.isminutes ? (1==i ? "15" : 2==i ? "30" : "60") : "1D"

numberTF = input(1)

source = close
length = 14

resolution_squeeze(D)=>
    ma = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, D, ta.sma(source,length))
    bb = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, D, ta.stdev(source,length))
    kc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, D, ta.sma(ta.tr,length))
    upBB = ma + bb * 2
    lowBB = ma - bb * 2
    upKCWide = ma + kc * 2
    lowKCWide = ma - kc * 2
    upKCNormal = ma + kc * 1.5
    lowKCNormal = ma - kc * 1.5
    upKCNarrow = ma + kc
    lowKCNarrow = ma - kc
    
    //Squeeze Type
    sqzOnWide  = (lowBB >= lowKCWide) and (upBB <= upKCWide) //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK
    sqzOnNormal  = (lowBB >= lowKCNormal) and (upBB <= upKCNormal) //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED
    sqzOnNarrow  = (lowBB >= lowKCNarrow) and (upBB <= upKCNarrow) //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE
    sqzOffWide = (lowBB < lowKCWide) and (upBB > upKCWide) //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN
    noSqz  = (sqzOnWide == false) and (sqzOffWide == false) //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE
    
    //Squeeze Color
    sq_color = noSqz ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow ? color.orange : sqzOnNormal ? color.red : sqzOnWide ? color.black : color.lime
    sq_color

c = resolution_squeeze(selectTF(numberTF))
plot(1, color = c)
```